# Recursion - splitting a group.

Tags: primitives, recursion

I've been trying to understand the notion of recursion in TeX - not easy given that my background is the high-level stuff in LaTeX. The only examples I can (just about) understand are very basic for-loop constructions, but I don't really feel like I have a picture for what expansion is or how it works.

I'd like to write a function that will take as its argument a group

```
{{#1}{#2}...{#n}}
```

where n can take any positive-integer value, and return the pair of groups

```
{#1}{{#2}...{#n}},
```

when n is at least 2, and `{#1}` otherwise.

This seems like it should be reasonably simple to do, but I don't know how I'd go about it.

**edit:** I want to use this function in beamer to progressively overlay lines inside AMSMath environments such that

- Vertical spacing is preserved;
- Equation numbering (where applicable) appears  in-time with the displayed lines of the equation array, and is preserved (i.e. not incremented) between overlays.

Comment: Where does the recursion come in?

Comment: @joseph, I've edited the question to include some context. I initially had it in there, but must have edited the question after I decided what tags it should have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\catcode`@=11
\def\splitarg#1{\@splitarg#1\@nil}
\def\@splitarg#1#2\@nil{{#1}\if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax\else{#2}\fi}
\catcode`@=12

\edef\x{\splitarg{{a}{b}{c}}}\show\x
\edef\x{\splitarg{{a}}}\show\x
```

Requires e-TeX, so you must process the example with pdftex, xetex, or luatex (not Knuth's tex). The test `\if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax` is true when #2 is empty (that is, when there is only one element in the list you pass to `\splitarg`) and e-TeX finds nothing in the "true" part; otherwise e-TeX braces what remains in the original list.

Comment: Would be more or less my approach too: the test is doable without e-TeX, but why tie one hand behind your back :-)

Comment: "you must process the example with pdftex" Works fine with xetex.

Comment: @morbusg: I meant "pdftex" as opposed to "tex", but you're right.

Comment: @Joseph: my opinion is the same; this test is more robust and expandable, without the need of taking into account many possibilities as it would be the case with original TeX.